# How to point to an array pointer (array [x]) in c

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I've just gotten done with a program that I have been working on and it works properly, but I want to improve upon it by eliminating the repeated code. So I figure I could do this by pointing to the array pointer itself, but I'm not too sure how to do this. My professor didn't go into great detail about this.

I am thinking that if I change the occurrences of `balance [0-4]` with something along the lines of `balance [x] = deposit_choice - 1` I'd be on the right track in eliminating repeated code, but nothing works as I expected it to. I've tried creating two different functions; one to change the value of `balance [x]` and one to run the algorithm, but I got a bit stuck on what to do.

Since they didn't work very well here is the first iteration of the algorithm unaltered:

```
case 3:
          show_account_menu(balance, 5);
          printf("An account balance of -1.00 means your account has not been opened yet.\n\n");
          printf("\nWhat account would you like to deposit in?\n" );// inputprompt
          scanf(" %d", &deposit_choice);
          if ((deposit_choice > 5) || (account_choice <1)){ //can only deposit in accounts 1-5
            printf("\n***  Invalid account selection!!  ***\n");
          }

            // start of account 1
            if(deposit_choice == 1){
              if(balance [0] == -1.00 ){
                printf("You have not created an account yet.\n");
                break;

              }else if (balance [0] >= 0.00){
                  printf("Enter an amount to deposit: ");//input
                  scanf("%d", &deposit);
                  printf("\n-------------------------------\n");
                    if(deposit >= 0){
                      printf("\n* Your new balance is: %.2f *\n\n",balance[0]=balance[0]+deposit);
                      break;
                    }else{
                      printf("Invalid input!\n\n");//deposit validation
                      break;
                    }
                  }

                //start of account 2
              }else if(deposit_choice == 2){
```

If anyone could help me out I would really appreciate it. I feel if i could understand how to tackle this, I would be able to cement how to work pointers, arrays, and maybe even functions.

If you want to look at the whole entire code here its is:

```
      #include <stdio.h>

    void show_bank_menu(void){
      printf("\n**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-Welcome to Scrubs Bank-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-\n");
      printf("**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**How may I help you today**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-\n");
      printf("********************~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~********************\n");
      printf("**********$$$$$$****~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~******$$$$$$$*******\n");
      printf("********$$$$$$$$$***  1. View Accounts...          *****$$$$$$$$$******\n");    /*introduction*/
      printf("********$$$$**$$$$**  2. Open Accounts...          ****$$$$**$$$$******\n");
      printf("********$$$$********  3. Deposit...                **********$$$$******\n");
      printf("***$$$$**$$$********  4. Withdraw...               **********$$$***$$$*\n");
      printf("***$$$$$$$$$********  5. Exit                      **********$$$$$$$$**\n");
      printf("****$$$$$$$*********~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~***********$$$$$$***\n");
      printf("********************~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~********************\n");
      printf("**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**\n");
      printf("**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**-**\n");
    }

    void show_account_menu(float array[ ], int size ){
      int x;
      for( x = 0 ; x < size ; x++ ) {
        printf("%d: %.2f\n", x+1, array[x]);
      }
    }



    int main (void) {
      int choice, account_choice, deposit_choice, withdraw_choice;
      float balance [5]= {-1.00,-1.00,-1.00,-1.00,-1.00};
      int deposit=0;
      int withdraw=0;

        //bank menu selection
        show_bank_menu();
        printf("\nchoice: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        while (choice !=5){
          switch(choice){
            case 1:
    //show account
            show_account_menu(balance,5);
            printf("An account balance of -1.00 means your account has not been opened yet.\n\n");
              break;

              case 2:
              show_account_menu(balance,5);
              printf("An account balance of -1.00 means your account has not been opened yet.\n\n");
                printf("Which account would you like to open?\n" );
                scanf("%d", &account_choice );
                if ((account_choice > 5) || (account_choice <1)){
                  printf("\n***  Invalid account selection!!  ***\n");
                }
    //open account
                  if(account_choice == 1){
                    printf("\n");
                    balance [0]=0.00;
                    show_account_menu(balance,5);
                  }else if(account_choice == 2){
                    printf("\n");
                    balance [1]=0.00;
                    show_account_menu(balance,5);
                  }else if(account_choice == 3){
                    printf("\n");
                    balance [2]=0.00;
                    show_account_menu(balance,5);
                  }else if(account_choice == 4){
                    printf("\n");
                    balance [3]=0.00;
                    show_account_menu(balance,5);
                  }else if(account_choice == 5){
                    printf("\n");
                    balance [4]=0.00;
                    show_account_menu(balance,5);
                  }
                  break;
    //deposit
                  case 3:
                  show_account_menu(balance, 5);
                  printf("An account balance of -1.00 means your account has not been opened yet.\n\n");
                  printf("\nWhat account would you like to deposit in?\n" );// inputprompt
                  scanf(" %d", &deposit_choice);
                  if ((deposit_choice > 5) || (account_choice <1)){
                    printf("\n***  Invalid account selection!!  ***\n");
                  }

                    // start of account 1
                    if(deposit_choice == 1){
                      if(balance [0] == -1.00 ){
                        printf("You have not created an account yet.\n");
                        break;

                      }else if (balance [0] >= 0.00){
                          printf("Enter an amount to deposit: ");//input
                          scanf("%d", &deposit);
                          printf("\n-------------------------------\n");
                            if(deposit >= 0){
                              printf("\n* Your new balance is: %.2f *\n\n",balance[0]=balance[0]+deposit);
                              break;
                            }else{
                              printf("Invalid input!\n\n");//deposit validation
                              break;
                            }
                          }

                        //start of account 2
                      }else if(deposit_choice == 2){
                        if (balance [1] == -1.00){
                          printf("You have not created an account yet.\n" );
                          break;

                        }else if(balance [1] >= 0.00){
                        printf("Enter an amount to deposit: ");
                        scanf("%d", &deposit);//input
                        printf("\n-------------------------------\n");
                          if(deposit >= 0){
                            printf("\n* Your new balance is: %.2f *\n\n",balance[1]=balance[1]+deposit);
                            break;
                          }else{            //validation
                            printf("Invalid input!\n\n");
                            break;
                          }
                        }


                      }else if(deposit_choice == 3){//start account 3
                        if(balance [2] == -1.00){
                          printf("You have not created an account yet.\n");
                          break;

                        }else if(balance [2] >= 0.00){
                        printf("Enter an amount to deposit: ");
                        scanf("%d", &deposit);                      //input
                        printf("\n-------------------------------\n");
                          if(deposit >= 0){
                            printf("\n* Your new balance is: %.2f *\n\n",balance[2]=balance[2]+deposit);
                            break;
                          }else{
                            printf("Invalid input!\n\n");//validation
                            break;
                          }
                        }

                      }else if(deposit_choice == 4){
                        if (balance [3] == -1.00){
                          printf("You have not created an account yet.\n" );
                          break;

                        }else if(balance [3] >= 0.00){
                        printf("Enter an amount to deposit: ");
                        scanf("%d", &deposit);//input
                        printf("\n-------------------------------\n");
                          if(deposit >= 0){
                            printf("\n* Your new balance is: %.2f *\n\n",balance[3]=balance[3]+deposit);
                            break;
                          }else{            //validation
                            printf("Invalid input!\n\n");
                            break;
                          }
                        }


                      }else if(deposit_choice == 5){// start account 5
                        if (balance [4] == -1.00){
                          printf("You have not opened the account yet.\n");
                          break;

                        }else if(balance [4] >= 0.00){
                        printf("Enter an amount to deposit: ");
                        scanf("%d", &deposit);                  //input
                        printf("\n-------------------------------\n");
                          if(deposit >= 0){
                            printf("\n* Your new balance is: %.2f *\n\n",balance[4]=balance[4]+deposit);
                            break;
                          }else{
                            printf("Invalid input!\n\n");    //validation
                            break;
                           }
                         }
                       }
    //end of withdraw options
                    break;
    //withdraw
                    case 4:
                    show_account_menu(balance, 5);
                    printf("An account balance of -1.00 means your account has not been opened yet.\n\n");
                    printf("\nWhat account would you like to withdraw out of?\n" );// inputprompt
                    scanf(" %d", &withdraw_choice);
                    if ((withdraw_choice > 5) || (account_choice <1)){
                      printf("\n***  Invalid account selection!!  ***\n");
                    }

                      // start of account 1
                      if(withdraw_choice == 1){
                        if(balance [0] == -1.00 ){
                          printf("You have not created an account yet.\n");
                          break;

                        }else if (balance [0] >= 0.00){
                            printf("Enter an amount to withdraw: ");//input
                            scanf("%d", &withdraw);
                            printf("\n-------------------------------\n");
                              if(withdraw > balance [0] ){
                                printf("\nInsufficient funds!\n");
                                break;
                              }else if(withdraw >= 0){
                                printf("\n* Your new balance is: %.2f *\n\n",balance[0]=balance[0]-withdraw);
                                break;
                              }else{
                                printf("Invalid input!\n\n");//deposit validation
                                break;
                              }
                            }

                          //start of account 2
                        }else if(withdraw_choice == 2){
                          if (balance [1] == -1.00){
                            printf("You have not created an account yet.\n" );
                            break;

                          }else if(balance [1] >= 0.00){
                            printf("Enter an amount to withdraw: ");
                            scanf("%d", &withdraw);//input
                            printf("\n-------------------------------\n");
                              if( withdraw > balance [1] ){
                                printf("Insufficient funds!\n");
                                break;
                              }else if(withdraw >= 0){
                                printf("\n* Your new balance is: %.2f *\n\n",balance[1]=balance[1]-withdraw);
                                break;
                              }else{            //validation
                                printf("Invalid input!\n\n");
                                break;
                              }
                            }

                          //start of account 3
                        }else if(withdraw_choice == 3){
                          if (balance [2] == -1.00){
                          printf("You have not created an account yet.\n");
                          break;

                          }else if(balance [2] >= 0.00){
                            printf("Enter an amount to withdraw: ");
                            scanf("%d", &withdraw);//input
                            printf("\n-------------------------------\n");
                              if(withdraw > balance [2] ){
                                printf("Insufficient funds!\n");
                                break;
                              }else if(withdraw >= 0){
                                printf("\n* Your new balance is: %.2f *\n\n",balance[2]=balance[2]-withdraw);
                                break;
                              }else{            //validation
                                printf("Invalid input!\n\n");
                                break;
                            }
                          }
                        //start of account 4
                      }else if(withdraw_choice == 4){
                        if (balance [3] == -1.00){
                        printf("You have not created an account yet.\n");
                        break;

                        }else if(balance [3] >= 0.00){
                          printf("Enter an amount to withdraw: ");
                          scanf("%d", &withdraw);//input
                          printf("\n-------------------------------\n");
                          if(withdraw > balance [3] ){
                            printf("Insufficient funds!\n");
                          }else if(withdraw >= 0){
                              printf("\n* Your new balance is: %.2f *\n\n",balance[3]=balance[3]-withdraw);
                              break;
                            }else{            //validation
                              printf("Invalid input!\n\n");
                              break;
                            }
                          }
                        //start of account 5
                      }else if(withdraw_choice == 5){
                        if (balance [4] == -1.00){
                        printf("You have not created an account yet.\n");
                        break;

                        }else if(balance [4] >= 0.00){
                          printf("Enter an amount to withdraw: ");
                          scanf("%d", &withdraw);//input
                          printf("\n-------------------------------\n");
                            if(withdraw > balance [4] ){
                              printf("Insufficient funds!\n");
                            }else if(withdraw >= 0){
                                printf("\n* Your new balance is: %.2f *\n\n",balance[4]=balance[4]-withdraw);
                                break;
                            }else{            //validation
                              printf("Invalid input!\n\n");
                              break;
                            }
                          }
                        }


                  /*open accounts*/
                        break;

                          case 5:
                            printf("\nGood day!\n");
                          return 0;


                    default:
                    printf("-----------------------");
                    printf("\n Not an option!\n");
                    printf("-----------------------\n");

        }// end switch

        show_bank_menu();

        printf("choice: ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);
        printf("\n");




      }//end while

      return 0;
    }//end main
```

Comment: Could you also add the code in which you tried to remove the repetition but didn't work?

Comment: It looks like what you're after is `balance[deposit_choice - 1]`.  Be sure to first validate that `deposit_choice` is in the range 1 - 5, and be sure to make that substitution everywhere in the block.  You should then not need to repeat the same code for each account.

Comment: Wow thanks guys! I cant believe it was that easy, i guess i just couldn't believe it was that easy!
Also I fixed the formatting of my indentations.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were looking for? Notice that instances of `balance[0]` were replaced with `balance[deposit_choice - 1]`:

```
          if(balance [deposit_choice - 1] == -1.00 ){
              printf("You have not created an account yet.\n");
              break;

          }else if (balance [deposit_choice - 1] >= 0.00){
              printf("Enter an amount to deposit: ");//input
              scanf("%d", &deposit);
              printf("\n-------------------------------\n");
              if(deposit >= 0){
                printf("\n* Your new balance is: %.2f *\n\n",balance[deposit_choice - 1] = balance[deposit_choice - 1] + deposit);
                break;
              }else{
                printf("Invalid input!\n\n");//deposit validation
                break;
              }
          }
```

P.S. Your indentations are screwy. You should make sure your indentations are always the same amount, and furthermore, add indentations for the INSIDE of a block (i.e. I noticed you indent `if` statements, but the indentation should start the line after).

Comment: And for old people, 1-2 chars of indention is not enough to make the blocks easily distinguishable. A standard 4-chars per-level is good -- even for the infirm.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to C :-)
That is a nice starter program, your instincts about reducing common code are going to serve you well.

I would suggest at using your account ID as an index in the balances instead of hardwiring your index.
I think this is what you were shooting for in the original question, you came very close.
Compare the "modified" version with the "original" version below.
The validation logic for entering an account ID is fine.
After you validate the account (e.g. 1 - 5 ) you can subtract one and index your balance array directly.

There are some other things you can do to consolidate your code.
If they haven't gotten into returning values from a function (e.g. void fncts only thus far) then this might be a good place to stop for now.
For example, your menu functions could actually return the choice, and you'd consolidate a fair number of scanf()s and other input validation.

*** Modified ***
Caution: I haven't actually tried compiling this code to make sure it works, but I hope the idea is clear.

```
case 3:
show_account_menu(balance, 5);
printf("An account balance of -1.00 means your account has not been opened yet.\n\n");
printf("\nWhat account would you like to deposit in?\n" );// inputprompt
scanf(" %d", &deposit_choice);
if ((deposit_choice > 5) || (account_choice <1)){
  printf("\n***  Invalid account selection!!  ***\n");
}
// NEW - this was the tricky part.
deposit_choice = deposit_choice - 1;

// delete // start of account 1
// delete if(deposit_choice == 1){
// dont need to do this, we know deposit_choice is smth from 0 thru 4 (e.g. acct#'s 1 thru 5).
// === start of deposit for *all* accounts ===
   // NEW - use deposit_choice to indicate which balance they wanted to work with.
   if(balance [deposit_choice] == -1.00 ) {
      printf("You have not created an account yet.\n");
      break;
   } else if (balance [deposit_choice] >= 0.00) {
      printf("Enter an amount to deposit: ");//input
      scanf("%d", &deposit);
      printf("\n-------------------------------\n");
      if(deposit >= 0){
         //original: printf("\n* Your new balance is: %.2f *\n\n",balance[0]=balance[0]+deposit);
         //style note: easier to read if you keep assignment logic outside of printing.
         //note how we modify balance, then print out the new one.
         balance[deposit_choice] = balance[deposit_choice] + deposit;
         printf("\n* Your new balance is: %.2f *\n\n",balance[deposit_choice] );
         break;
      }else{
         printf("Invalid input!\n\n");//deposit validation
         break;
      }
   }
// delete: //start of account 2
// delete: } else if(deposit_choice == 2) {
// delete:      if (balance [1] == -1.00){
// delete:        printf("You have not created an account yet.\n" );
// delete:        break;
// delete: ...etc. for accounts 3, 4 & 5 deposit handling.
```

Original: from long listing...

```
case 3:
show_account_menu(balance, 5);
printf("An account balance of -1.00 means your account has not been opened yet.\n\n");
printf("\nWhat account would you like to deposit in?\n" );// inputprompt
scanf(" %d", &deposit_choice);
if ((deposit_choice > 5) || (account_choice <1)){
  printf("\n***  Invalid account selection!!  ***\n");
}

// start of account 1
if(deposit_choice == 1){
   if(balance [0] == -1.00 ) {
      printf("You have not created an account yet.\n");
      break;
   } else if (balance [0] >= 0.00) {
      printf("Enter an amount to deposit: ");//input
      scanf("%d", &deposit);
      printf("\n-------------------------------\n");
      if(deposit >= 0){
      printf("\n* Your new balance is: %.2f *\n\n",balance[0]=balance[0]+deposit);
      break;
      }else{
      printf("Invalid input!\n\n");//deposit validation
      break;
      }
   }
//start of account 2
} else if(deposit_choice == 2) {
   if (balance [1] == -1.00) {
      printf("You have not created an account yet.\n" );
      break;
```

added elaboration: A array is essentially just a pointer, the index notation with the square braces is a convenience to let the compiler figure out the actual offsets in memory to use (doubles tend to be longer than chars, for example, so the actual byte offsets will be different for mychars[5] vs. mydoubles[5] (the former might really just be 5 bytes down-range from the start of mychars, while the later might be 5*8=40 bytes downrange, or however many bytes long a double is on your particular cpu + compiler).  I know the cool kids these days will talk about size_t and so on.  Just for fun, try the following:

```
printf( "char: %d\n",   sizeof(char) );
printf( "short: %d\n",  sizeof(short) );
printf( "int: %d\n",    sizeof(int) );
printf( "long: %d\n",   sizeof(long) );
printf( "float: %d\n",  sizeof(float) );
printf( "double: %d\n", sizeof(double) );
```